# Hibernate, and wake up upon connection to a port

Tags: networking, windows-10, plex

So I have a desktop that I'll be replacing with a new build shortly. I'd like to continue running a Plex server on my old one headlessly, but don't want the computer to be on all the time. Is there a way to run the desktop in very low power mode until the OS detects an attempted TCP connection on a given port and then it'll wake itself up. It should hibernate if there have been no open connections on the port for x amount of time.

What I would expect from this, is a device connecting to Plex when it's hibernating will be slow. May even timeout until you try and connect. But once connected it would be a normal experience.

Windows 10 for reference. Though I'm open to installing any OS for this purpose.

Comment: Your looking for Wake On LAN (WoL).  However, spinning down and spinning up mechanical drives are not actually good for those mechanical drives.  Questions seeking hardware and/or software recommendations are out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an Ethernet card that supports "Wake on pattern match". (I believe most do nowadays, even the built-in ones on motherboards, but have a good look through the specs anyway.) Once the feature is enabled through device settings, along with Wake-on-LAN support in general, the system should wake up in response to any connection.

However, I think the "very low power mode" most apropriate for your purpose would be suspend-to-RAM, not hibernation. While it's technically possible to wake a system from hibernation or even from full shutdown, I'm not sure if all motherboards actually support keeping the Ethernet card powered on in these states, whereas waking from suspend-to-RAM is going to work 99% of the time – as well as providing near-instant wakeup and providing almost the same power savings.

---

Note that this requires matching more than just TCP – the computer must already wake up when it sees an ARP or ICMPv6 ND request, because if those aren't replied to, then the router won't even be able to send you the initial TCP packet.

For that reason, Windows always includes [ARP and ND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/941145/unwanted-wake-up-events-may-occur-when-you-enable-the-wake-on-lan-feat) whenever you enable "Wake on pattern" – it doesn't need to include TCP specifically and it has no way of limiting TCP ports either (both because the computer will already be awake at that point)

---

> if including ARP, won't the computer just get arbitrarily woken up sometimes?

It probably will. If that's an issue, you should probably use traditional "Wake on magic packet" WoL (i.e. manual wake using a tool such as wol.exe).

Comment: The router doesn't have to send ARP requests on every request right? It holds cache for done period of time I would assume. I'm not an expert on the protocol though.

Comment: Also, if including ARP, won't the computer just get arbitrarily woken up sometimes?

Comment: Yes, all hosts and routers keep an "ARP cache" so they don't need to send ARP requests often... However, if the cache entry is inactive for more than 10–20 minutes, it simply expires and the MAC address is forgotten. So if your server has been sleeping for the past several hours, the router _will_ need to ARP for it again. _(Many routers allow configuring "static" ARP entries, but Windows' WoL function works on the assumption of ordinary dynamic ARP.)_

Comment: And yes, if you include ARP as a wake pattern, the system will be woken up as soon as anything tries to contact its IP address for any reason. That's usually unavoidable; mitigate that by using a relatively short auto-suspend timer. (That said, if the router supported static ARP entries _and_ if the OS allowed you to customize the patterns, then you _could_ avoid this and only create a pattern for the TCP SYN packet on a specific port. It may be possible on Linux via ethtool, very unlikely on Windows.)

Comment: Is the wake on pattern match configurable? I've found very little on being able to tweak it over the last couple of days. I could get static ARP configured. Edit: you answered this as I was asking it lol. Thanks a lot, I'll do more digging into the capabilities of windows and my router

Comment: `ethtool` calls it "Wake on filter" and allows specifying the filters via --config-nfc. Windows doesn't.

Comment: I may consider installing Ubuntu on the machine then. My media is all on a separate hard drive anyway. Just need to check how Plex server runs on Ubuntu.